# How to show that this system is time invariant and linear?

Tags: linear-systems

I have a system described by the following difference equation:
$$y(n)−y(n+1) = 12x(n+2)$$
where $x(n)$ is the input, and $y(n)$ is the output.

How do I show that this system is time invariant and linear?

Comment: Could you please tell the community what you have tried so far, and where you are stuck at

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  As Laurent suggests, we can give you help, but we need you to show us where your understanding breaks down.  Please [edit your question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/84460/edit) and add the steps you've taken to try to solve the problem so far.  We can chime in with suggestions then.  The reason is that this question seems like a homework problem, and we won't do homework problems directly, but will certainly tutor towards a solution.